# innodb_buffer_pool_size complications

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, percona

I had some complications regarding `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. I read the official documentation, and I found out the formula **innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances.**

so if my `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` is 268435456, and my `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is 8, what should be my `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

how does this work?

Comment: I want to know innodb_buffer_pool_size parameter's relation with innodb_buffer_pool_instances and innodb_buffer_pool_size.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 16GB; what'll be the preferred innodb_buffer_pool_size, and if I increase my RAM to 32GB, what'll be the preferred size? How to set innodb_buffer_pool_size size according to my RAM? same goes for innodb_buffer_pool_instance and innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to calculate the pool size. Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to the *total* RAM you want to allocate to the buffer pool.

Let MySQL calculate the pool instances and chunk size. MySQL does this automatically by default.

In theory, you could fine-tune the pools and chunks. But it's almost certain that you don't have to do anything other than the default.

I've managed thousands of MySQL instances, for small instances and multi-terabyte instances, and I've never had to size the chunks and pools manually.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin, for your response.

So you're saying if I set the pool_size to = 32G, the innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size and innodb_buffer_pool_instances will be set accordingly?

Comment: Yes, for that size, there will be 8 pool instances and the chunk size will be 128MB. So each pool instance will be 4G, and there will be 32 chunks in each instance. You don't have to specify that in the configuration, it's handled by default.